# Uppercase first letter only using SSIS?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis

I using SSIS to edit an excel sheet for a task. One is to select a string column named 'name' and uppercase first letter only. I tried writing `UPPER(SUBSTRING(name,1,1))` but it only returned the first letter. Is there a way to return all names but the first letter only is Uppercased?

Comment: It seems that I can't find this 'CONCAT' function in the string functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate strings within SSIS expressions you use `+`:

```
upper(substring("name", 1, 1)) + substring("name", 2, len("name")-1)
```

For future reference on simple expressions like these, I would encourage you to have a quick look through the proper documentation, which is thorough and incredibly useful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/concatenate-ssis-expression